# Debugging Firebase Cloud Functions Timing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We have a completed web app that is set for release in two days time. For the last few months we have seen no issues, but after google cloud went down last Thursday/Friday, our response times for our cloud functions have massively increased, taking between 1-3 seconds.

I would like to debug this as get back to normal speed, as at the moment despite calling the same function many times a minute, it still responds like it is cold. I understand that cloud functions can have varying response times, but as mentioned above for all of development it was super fast. I’m not trying to rid of cold start times, but I do expect a warm function to behave as such.

Does anyone have suggestions on where I could start.

Just an FYI too, I am using an express type system when I only have 1 end point that calls functions based on the params I pass, this means that if I hit 1 function they all become warm as there is only 1 function. This is what has been working so well up until recently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Performance Monitoring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon)

To include the standard Performance Monitoring SDK, add the following scripts to the bottom of your  tag, but before you use any Firebase services:

```
<body>
  <!-- Insert these scripts at the bottom of the HTML, but before you use any Firebase services -->

  <!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <!-- Add the standard Performance Monitoring library -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.13.1/firebase-performance.js"></script>
<body>
```

Initialize Firebase and Performance Monitoring in your app:

```
<script>
  // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    // ...
  };

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  // Initialize Performance Monitoring and get a reference to the service
  var perf = firebase.performance();
</script>
</body>
```